# Comparing objects, checkbox checking, edit checkboxs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following line:

```
checked={this.state.peopleChecked.some(({ asset}) => asset['object'] ['user']['id'] === person.userCompetences.map((user, index) => {
   user['asset']['id']
 })
)}
```

I have a problem comparing two objects.
Compares a property from the array `people` ->`userCompetences` -> `asset` ->`id` with an object from the array `peopleChecked` ->`asset` -> `object` ->`user` - > `asset_id`.
if `id` from array`people` and `asset_id`, `id === asset_id` are equal to returns`true`. Checkbox is checked

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n2zkjk

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: [
            {
              firstname: "Paul",
              userCompetences: [
                { asset:{ 
                    id: "12345" 
                  }    
                }
              ]
            },
            {
                firstname: "Victor",
                userCompetences: [
                  {  asset: {
                        id: "5646535"     
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                firstname: "Martin",
                userCompetences: [
                  {  asset: {
                        id: "097867575675"     
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                firstname: "Gregor",
                userCompetences: [
                  {  asset: {
                        id: "67890"     
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
        ],
       peopleChecked: [   
          {
            amount: 0,
            asset: {
              id: "fgfgfgfg",
              object: {
                  competence: null,
                  id: "dsdsdsdsd",
                  user: {
                      firstname: "Gregor",
                      asset_id: "67890"
                  }
              }
            }
          },
           {
            amount: 0,
            asset: {
              id: "dsdsdsd",
              object: {
                  competence: null,
                  id: "wewewe",
                  user: {
                      firstname: "Paul",
                      asset_id: "12345"
                  }
              }
            }
          },
      ],
      selectPeopleId: []
    }
  }

  /*handleSelect = (person) => {

    //Check if clicked checkbox is already selected
    var found = this.state.peopleChecked.find((element) => {
      return element.id == person.id;
    });

    if(found){
      //If clicked checkbox already selected then remove that from peopleChecked array
      this.setState({
        peopleChecked: this.state.peopleChecked.filter(element => element.id !== person.id),
        selectPeopleId: this.state.selectPeopleId.filter(element => element !== person.id)
      }, () => console.log(this.state.peopleChecked))
    }else{
      //If clicked checkbox is not already selected then add that in peopleChecked array
      this.setState({
        selectPeopleId: [...this.state.selectPeopleId, person.id],
        peopleChecked: [...this.state.peopleChecked,person]
      }, () => {console.log(this.state.selectPeopleId);console.log(this.state.peopleChecked);})
    }
  }*/


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.people.map(person => (
          <div key={person.id} className="mb-1">
            <input 
              type={'checkbox'}
              id={person.id}
              label={person.firstname}
              checked={this.state.peopleChecked.some(({ asset}) => asset['object']['user']['id'] ===           person.userCompetences.map((user, index) => {
                  user['asset']['id']
                })
              )}
              onChange = {() => this.handleSelect(person)}
            /> {person.firstname}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correct checked code syntax would be below based on your data structure:
Issue was `asset_id` correct key was missing and map returns an array thus you would need its index, however in your case you can simply swap it with `person.userCompetences.[0]['asset']['id']` but I kept your syntax in case you want it for some other purpose.

```
  checked={
            this.state.peopleChecked.some(
              ({ asset }) => asset['object']['user']['asset_id'] === person.userCompetences.map(
                (user, index) => user['asset']['id']
              )[0]
          )}
```

However its inherently complicated and you should focus on untangling it by placing some cached `const` in your map function to keep track of what you are looking at. I would also advice to introduce some child component to render in the first `map` to make your life easier maintaining this code in the future.

Edited code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ptsnbc?file=index.js